# How to save multiple lists of dataframes and limit number of list elements that can be saved?

Tags: r, list, save, write.table

I have multiple lists with varying number of elements in each list as in screenshot.

[image]

My current code allows user to save one list at a time. But I am curious if there is a way I can allow user to save all the lists at once.

Additionally (if possible) I want to limit the number of list elements that can be downloaded at once. Lets say for a dataset, list contains 64 elements, but I want user to be able to download only 15 files at a time.

Current code goes like this:

```
saveFiles <- Function(list){
sapply(names(list), function(x) write.table(list[[x]], file= paste(x,".txt"), sep= "\t", quote=F))
}
```

Any advice how can this be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

## I am not sure I understand your question. is this any good?

```
library(tictoc) #measure time difference
library(doParallel)

LIST<-lapply(1:150, function(X) X) #create data
names(LIST)<-1:150

doParallel::registerDoParallel(5)
# run in parallel 
tic()
foreach(list=LIST) %dopar% {
  write.table(LIST[[list]], file= paste(list,".txt"), sep= "\t", quote=F)
}
toc()

# regular loop
tic()
for(list in LIST) {
  write.table(LIST[[list]], file= paste(list,".txt"), sep= "\t", quote=F)
}
toc()
```

Comment: In your code as well, I am only able to save 1 list (with 150 elements) at a time. 
I have attached a screenshot in my question. I want to create a function that allows all the lists in environment (in above example there are 5) to be saved at once. Instead of calling function to save a single list.

Comment: @Gen, By default R use one core and thus, can write one file at a time. What I tried to do in my code is to use the "doParallel" package to write 5 at once using 5 cores ( under the "# run in parallel"). I also write a regular loop after that to measure the time difference (measured using the "tictoc" package).
Note that your CPU must have more than one core to be able to write in parallel.
The list in my example is just used to supply data to be written in parallel. You can create one list containing your five lists inside, and use my example to write them all at once.